# How to make pycharm keep old projects visible in left-side projects tab?

Tags: pycharm

When I open new project in Pycharm, last project form left-side project tab disappears, and finding setting to fix this from settings itself/ google seems excessively tough.

So, how to get left-side tab to keep old projects visible until I manually delete them from there?

First time I installed Pycharm it was initially that way, but now after win10 installion, it seems not to be. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling too already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While opening a new project, in the displayed `Open Project` dialog,

select `Open in the current window` radio button, and check `Add to currently opened projects` checkbox,

The new project will be opened along with the previous project.

[image]